# Get selected text from drop down list using name attribute jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the selected value from the dropdown.

I am creating the controls dynamically. I am not using ID attribute to avoid the problem of having multiple controls with the same ID/ duplicate IDs.

Here is how I am able to get the values of the textbox controls

```
$('.btn-success').off('click').on('click', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(this).closest(".row");
    var lnameval = row.find("input[name='ContactLastName']").val();        
});
```

Is it possible to get the selected value of the dropdown using the `name` attribute.

something like :   `var titleVal = row.find("input[name='ContactTitle']").val();`

HTML :

```
 <form id="formAddContact"  role="form" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="errorMessageContainer2" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;">
                    <ul id="messageBox2" class="list-unstyled"></ul>
                </div>
@foreach (string cInfo in Model.emailList)
        {

    <div class="row" id="@cInfo.Replace("@","")" style="display: none;">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3 control-label">
                    <label>Title:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select class="form-control ToCapture"  name="ContactTitle">
                        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                        <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3 control-label">
                    <label id="lblfname">First Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input  maxlength="50" name="ContactFirstName" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3 control-label">
                    <label id="lbllname">Last Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input  maxlength="50" name="ContactLastName" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">                 
        <input type="button" value="Add Contact"   class="btn btn-success">
        <input type="button" value="Cancel"  class="btn btn-default">    
    </div>
    <br/>
        }
                <hr />
            </div>           

    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little change needed :

```
row.find("select[name='ContactTitle']").val();
```

It's not an input.